# how to query the whole Realm database for a specific data and not only from a specific field or attribute

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a realm database with a table with 5 fields. The fields are "clientName", "occasions" , "venue" , "time"  and "date". In the display in uitableview I would be able to display all the data according to the clientName using :

```
 allEvent = realm.objects(AllEventClass.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "clientName", ascending: true)
```

Now I want to set up a UISearchBar with a function to search the whole database irrespective of fields. No matter what data from any field the user entered into the searchbar, the tableview will show the result in clientName which is related to the searched data entered. For now I can search the database only using the clientName field and the result would of course be the clientName. For instance it would be a problem if I only remember the "date" but I could not remember the clientName associated with that "date". I want to be able to enter the "date" or any data from any other fields and still be given the clientName result associated with it. For now this is the only code available to me.

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    allEvent = AllEventClasses?.filter("clientName CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchBar.text!).sorted(byKeyPath: "clientName", ascending: true)


    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question may be asking one of a couple of questions. Let me address two. For clarity, a Realm Database will contain objects and those objects will have properties (fields). So there isn't really a table with fields (as that's a bit generic) so any queries will be performed against those objects and their properties.

You may be asking how to query across all objects in your database at the same time.

A Realm Result is a homogenous collection type, so you can't store different subclasses of Object in the same Results object - that means you can't perform a query across multiple objects and return the results into one Result object. One simple solution is to query on each object type.

However, I think your actual question is asking how to query across multiple properties within an object. So assuming your object looks like this

```
class AllEventClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var clientName = ""
    @objc dynamic var occassions = ""
    @objc dynamic var venue = ""
    @objc dynamic var time = ""
    @objc dynamic var date = ""
}
```

and suppose you want to query for any matches in the clientName, occassions and date properties.

```
let search = stringFromSearchBar
let eventResults = realm.objects(AllEventClass.self).filter("clientName contains[cd] %@ or date contains[cd] %@ or occassions contains[cd] %@", search, search, search)
```

let me know if you asked something else and  I will update the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Jay. Your answer was spot on. Maybe I did not put the question correctly  nevertheless you've understood what I meant. Your codes work great. Thank you again. Maybe you would like to answer my other question.