# How to properly use generics in Swift to store different types of objects in a list in Realm?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am having a problem of Realm throwing an error that states that my type 'Category' is not managed by Realm.

For context, a 'Category' can hold either a collection of type 'Mistakes' or 'Subjects'. A 'Subject' can also contain a collection of 'Category' containing a collection of 'Mistake'. Thus, I am using generics so that I do not have to create two separate data models to group these two data models.

```
class Category<O:Object>:Object{

//properties
@objc dynamic var categoryName:String = ""

//relationships
let ChildObjects = List<O>() //type of child object is to be set by the generic type; two possible types: subjects & mistakes

//mother objects
var Subjects = LinkingObjects(fromType: Subject.self, property: "MistakeCategories") //For Mistake Categories

}
```

I load the results of a category of subjects, using the following code:

```
var CategoryDatabase:Results<Category<Subject>>!

CategoryDatabase = R.objects(Category<Subject>.self)
```

I have also tried using the following code:

```
var CategoryDatabase:Results<Category<Subject>>!

CategoryDatabase = R.objects(Category.self)
```

Nonetheless, I am having the error below.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Object type '_TtGC8Go_For_A8CategoryCSo16RealmSwiftObject_' not managed by the Realm'
```

I have tried to search the internet for possible solutions but they their problems aren't exactly the same as mine. Nonetheless, I found [this](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3635) which could be a possible answer as to why I am getting the error. However, the error and its cause is different.

Comment: I think the problem here with generic type of Category<O:Object>:Object it looks like Realm does not support this type of classes, so maybe solution is to avoid it and create two lists of child objects - one for mistakes and another for subjects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not going to work

```
let ChildObjects = List<O>() //...two possible types: subjects & mistakes
```

[Realm Collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/collections/#collections) (Result, List) are homogenous and can only store zero or more instances of one object type; e.g. you can't store different classes of Object in the same List object

Generics are great but when you're working with different (possibly unrelated) objects, subjects and mistakes, using a generic is probably the wrong approach because queries and the actually data will be quite different.

Keep your data separate

```
let subjects = List<SubjectClass>()
```

and

```
let mistakes = List<MistakeClass>()
```

of if there is some connection make it one class

```
class SubjectClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var subject_name = ""
    @objc dynamic var is_mistake = false
}
```

of if a subject can have lots of mistakes

```
class SubjectClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var subject_name = ""
    let allMyMistakes = List<MistakeClass<>
}
```

For some data modeling info, review [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54156871/how-to-query-the-whole-realm-database-for-a-specific-data-and-not-only-from-a-sp/54161102#54161102) and then a fantasic answer from @DávidPásztor [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48125923/realmswift-cannot-cast-resultssomeojbect-to-resultsobject/48126909#48126909)

Answer (score 0):

This is my generic function that worked properly when storing different types of objects into Realm database:

```
let realm = try! Realm()

func createObject<T: Object>(_ object: T) {
     do {
         try realm.write {
             realm.add(object)
           }
        } catch {
             print(error)
           }
        }
```